How to fix compile problem in AG Grid React?
I get the following error when I try make a basic grid with React:
***ERROR in ./node_modules/ag-grid-react/dist/package/index.esm.mjs 2611:52-62
Can't import the named export 'useState' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)***

Can anybody tell me what is wrong and what I can do to resolve it?
